# Which library should I use?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cross-browser

I  need to design an interface, where user can drag drop elements into page and design a web page. User will be restricted to add elements only to content area and elements which are added to content area also can be nested. For example, an image can be nested inside a paragraph. 
I have tried using jquery and was successful up to some extent.

I would appreciate if some one helps me to choose a stable, cross browser compatible library for this functionality.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I removed the php tag, has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).**

It has the drag and drop functionality and you can use it easily.

I think you should go with jquery. (one more thing if you stuck somewhere there are many stackers on SO to help you out).

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI as Mevada suggested http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/ or prototype+scriptaculous http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/droppables

There are more alternatives but jquery is the preffered way to go for this thing lately as it is used by some major corporations and that creates the illusion of "sable and good stuff"...and it is pretty good actually:)

Comment: Thanks Quamis and Mevada !
I have selected Jquery..but I still find it difficult for some things as - 1) Making the new elements draggable
2) Nesting of elements
3) Events such as click of new elements do not work
I think I need to polish more... :)
I have not gone through the link provided by Quamis, tomorrow will do it.
More links are welcome.
Thanks again